# How to single check at a time out of all Radiobuttons in listview using RecyclerView?

Tags: android

I want to do this->(only 1 button is checked Rest all is unchecked or all are unchecked)

From what i have done i achieved this:
(at first all are unchecked)

clicked button3. Its checked

Then button3 clicked it goes unchecked.
Then again button3 clicked it goes checked.
(uptill now everything is fine )...........

But error comes here...-> now if i clicked button4 or any other  both button4/other1  and button3 are checked...i wnt only button4 checked now but its not happening.

But this error does not come when i clicked  different buttons at all time i mean button1 then 2 then 3 .....so on.

Help me guyz.....
This are my files.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 

MyAdapter.OnClickListener {


    RadioButton previousRb;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    List<ButtonList> buttonList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonList.add(new ButtonList("Button1"));
        buttonList.add(new ButtonList("Button2"));
        buttonList.add(new ButtonList("Button3"));
        buttonList.add(new ButtonList("Button4"));
        buttonList.add(new ButtonList("Button5"));
        buttonList.add(new ButtonList("Button6"));
        buttonList.add(new ButtonList("Button7"));
        buttonList.add(new ButtonList("Button8"));


        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(buttonList, this);

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(RadioButton rb, int position) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        if (previousRb != null && previousRb.isChecked() == true) {
            previousRb.setChecked(false);
            previousRb = null;
        } else if (rb == previousRb) {
            rb.setChecked(false);
            return;
        } else {
            rb.setChecked(true);

            previousRb = rb;
        }

    }

}
```

MyAdapter.java

```
`   

        import android.content.Context;
        import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.RadioButton;

        import java.util.Collections;
        import java.util.List;

        public class MyAdapter extends              RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
            private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
            private List<ButtonList> buttonList = Collections.emptyList();



            private OnClickListener mOnClickListener;
            Context c;

            public MyAdapter(List<ButtonList> buttonList,OnClickListener mOnClickListener) {

                this.buttonList = buttonList;
                this.mOnClickListener=mOnClickListener;
            }


            @Override
            public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

                View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.radiobutton, viewGroup, false);
                ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
                return vh;
            }
            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

                ButtonList obj = buttonList.get(i);
                viewHolder.rb.setText(obj.getName());


            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return buttonList.size();
            }

            public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                RadioButton rb;
                public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
                    super(itemView);
                    rb = (RadioButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rbText);
                   rb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            mOnClickListener.onClick(rb,getPosition());
                        }


                    });
                }
            }

            public interface OnClickListener {
                void onClick(RadioButton rb,int position);
            }

        }
```

**ButtonList.java**

```
public class ButtonList {
    String name;


    public ButtonList(String name){
        this.name=name;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**radiobutton.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of doing these much stuff just change your bean and adapter as follow

ButtonList.java

```
public class ButtonList {
    String name;
    boolean isSelected;

    public ButtonList(String name,boolean isSelected){
        this.name=name;
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

   public boolean getSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean isSelected) {
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
buttonList.add(new ButtonList("Button1",false));
buttonList.add(new ButtonList("Button2",false));
buttonList.add(new ButtonList("Button3",false));
buttonList.add(new ButtonList("Button4",false));
buttonList.add(new ButtonList("Button5",false));
buttonList.add(new ButtonList("Button6",false));
buttonList.add(new ButtonList("Button7",false));
buttonList.add(new ButtonList("Button8",false));
```

change your onClick method to

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(RadioButton rb, int position) {

       for(int i=0;i<buttonList.size();i++){
          if(i==position){
              if(buttonList.get(i).getSelected())
                buttonList.get(i).setSelected(false);
           else
               buttonList.get(i).setSelected(true);
          }else{
             buttonList.setSelected(false);
         }
       }
       mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Inside your adapter

```
 @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

                ButtonList obj = buttonList.get(i);
                viewHolder.rb.setText(obj.getName());
                viewHolder.rb.setChecked(obj.getSelected());

            }
```

Thats it,

Comment: on tapping on single button twice its not unchecked

Comment: correction for ur onClick_>    ButtonList.get(i).setSelected(true)

Comment: i also want check/uncheck  on tapping...hlp plz  .ur suggestion nt worked on tapping the same button

Comment: yaa i did exactly wht u suggested. 2 errors come one in ButtonList.java and one in onClick.    here isSelected is boolean and return type is String -> 
   public String getSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

Comment: sorry my mistake...change method return type to boolean...as i did

Comment: is it working or not? if you found this helpful then please accept my answer and up vote it

Comment: its not working ...when unchecking the button by tapping it.

Comment: anytime...happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

Create static int in MainActivity

```
public static int mPosition = -1;
```

then modify your callback interface of MainActivity

```
@Override
public void onClick(RadioButton rb, int position) {
   if(rb.isChecked())
       mPosition = -1;
   else
       mPosition = position;
   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And last modify Adapter

```
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i)                 {

            ButtonList obj = buttonList.get(i);
            viewHolder.rb.setText(obj.getName());
            if(MainActivity.mPosition == i){
                  viewHolder.rb.setChecked(true);
            }else{
                  viewHolder.rb.setChecked(false);   
            }     
        }
```

Comment: i also want check/uncheck on tapping...hlp plz .ur suggestion nt worked on tapping the same button. i did wht u told

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you

`public class SearchAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable, View.OnClickListener {

```
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;

private HashMap<String, Object> temp;
private HashMap<String, Object> original;
private List<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<>();

public SearchAdapter(Context context, int resource, HashMap<String, Object> temp) {

    this.temp = temp;

    this.context = context;

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return ((List<String>) temp.get("name")).get(position).toString();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ((List<String>) temp.get("name")).size();
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_seach_item, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    String label = getItem(position);

    viewHolder.txtTitle.setText("" + label);
    viewHolder.eveIcon.setImageResource(((List<Integer>) temp.get("image")).get(position))


    if (selectedItems.contains(getItem(position))) {
        viewHolder.radioButton.setChecked(true);


    } else {
        viewHolder.radioButton.setChecked(false);
    }

    viewHolder.radioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!((List<Boolean>) temp.get("check")).get(position)) {
                ((List<Boolean>) temp.get("check")).remove(position);
                ((List<Boolean>) temp.get("check")).add(position, true);
                selectedItems.add(((List<String>) temp.get("name")).get(position).toString());
                Set<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
                hs.addAll(selectedItems);
                selectedItems.clear();
                selectedItems.addAll(hs);
                ((RadioButton) view).setChecked(true);

            } else {
                ((List<Boolean>) temp.get("check")).remove(position);
                ((List<Boolean>) temp.get("check")).add(position, false);
                selectedItems.remove(((List<String>) temp.get("name")).get(position).toString());

                ((RadioButton) view).setChecked(false);

            }


            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    });
    viewHolder.txtTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            if (!((List<Boolean>) temp.get("check")).get(position)) {
                ((List<Boolean>) temp.get("check")).remove(position);
                ((List<Boolean>) temp.get("check")).add(position, true);
                selectedItems.add(((List<String>) temp.get("name")).get(position).toString());
                Set<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
                hs.addAll(selectedItems);
                selectedItems.clear();
                selectedItems.addAll(hs);
                //((RadioButton) view).setChecked(true);

            } else {
                ((List<Boolean>) temp.get("check")).remove(position);
                ((List<Boolean>) temp.get("check")).add(position, false);
                selectedItems.remove(((List<String>) temp.get("name")).get(position).toString());

                // ((RadioButton) view).setChecked(false);

            }


            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

public List<String> getSelectedItems() {
    return selectedItems;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            temp = (HashMap<String, Object>) results.values; // has the filtered values
            notifyDataSetChanged();  // notifies the data with new filtered values
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
            HashMap<String, Object> FilteredArrList = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            if (original == null) {
                original = new HashMap<String, Object>(temp); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues
            }

            /********
             *
             *  If constraint(CharSequence that is received) is null returns the mOriginalValues(Original) values
             *  else does the Filtering and returns FilteredArrList(Filtered)
             *
             ********/
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                // set the Original result to return
                results.count = ((List<String>) original.get("name")).size();
                results.values = original;
            } else {
                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                List<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
                List<Integer> image = new ArrayList<>();
                List<Boolean> check = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < ((List<String>) original.get("name")).size(); i++) {
                    String data = ((List<String>) original.get("name")).get(i);
                    if (data.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString())) {


                        name.add(((List<String>) original.get("name")).get(i));
                        image.add(((List<Integer>) original.get("image")).get(i));
                        check.add(((List<Boolean>) original.get("check")).get(i));
                    }
                }
                FilteredArrList.put("name", name);
                FilteredArrList.put("image", image);
                FilteredArrList.put("check", check);
                // set the Filtered result to return
                results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                results.values = FilteredArrList;
            }
            return results;
        }
    };
    return filter;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

}


private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtTitle;
    ImageView eveIcon;
    RadioButton radioButton;

    public ViewHolder(View convertView) {
        txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.search_txt);
        eveIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.search_img);
        radioButton = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.search_radio);
    }
}
```

}`

This will listen each click in radio button and will higlights selected button and uncheck all other